# How do I design my Java class to use methods of a defined Utility class?

Tags: java, oop, selenium, webdriver

How do I design my Java class to properly extend a Utility class?   Here is a screenshot of how I do it currently but I suspect there is a better way to do this?  Am I using proper object oriented design here?   I do it this way because of the conundrum of needing to extend both the **required** LoadableComponent class and also have access to all the static methods in my own WebDriverUtils utility class. I am looking for a better idea since I am not a formally educated programmer.

In other words, a Utility class is not a "is a" and it is not a "has a", and so how does it fit into the world of oop?

If you want to see an example of how I have implemented this diagram, some code I wrote is here on GitHub, see [my project here](https://github.com/djangofan/WebDriverTestingTemplate).   If anyone wants to post a diagram of a proper way of doing this, that would be awesome also.

[image]

NOTE: In this diagram for a web browser test automation project, TabIFrameOne and tabIFrameTwo are page-objects that handle recognizing when a iframe finishes loading and identifying elements in the frame that can be interacted with.  DefaultPage is the main browser window DOM and does not represent the DOM inside iFrames.  Each iFrame class uses WebDriver PageFactory.initObjects() to load web elements.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here.  Can you post some actual (minimal) code, and explain what problem you're facing?

Comment: Ideally, you don't extend a utility class. Also, multiple inheritance is not supported in Java anyway.

Comment: Favor composition over inheritance. Don't extend a utility class instead compose a new utility class out of functionality in other utility classes through composition.

Comment: @Sudhanshu - right, I dont want to extend the utility class but I do want access to all the methods therein.

Comment: Composition is one of the options as suggested by @nattyddubbs. Often the utility methods can be made static.

Comment: By composition, do you mean create an instance of the Utility class within every class that needs to use those utilities?

Comment: You can make utility methods static. Or if WebDriver is going to be your root class in the hierarchy, put utility methods in that class.

Comment: The problem is that extending LoadableComponent is required by the API I am using.  I didn't want to have my utility class extend LoadableComponent in a hierarchy because a utility class is not a page object.  Therefore, the only way I knew of getting access to the methods in my utility class was via import static.  It appears from the answers to my question that I also have the option of creating instances of my utility class (composition)?   Which is preferred, I do not know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually partially solved this issue by passing a instance of a "private WebDriver" object into the class that I was previously trying to extend.  This allowed me to change the WebDriver object into a instance variable rather than a static shared object.

Here is a diagram of my solution.  It is better than it was.  Maybe it could still be improved.
[image]

Ultmately though, I will probably solve this with the use of [defender methods](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/Defender%20Methods%20v4.pdf) .  This is the pattern I now use for my [GitHub project here](https://github.com/djangofan/WebDriverTestingTemplate).

Answer (score 3):

I would say that inheritance would be a bad idea here.  A page might HAVE-A utility function, but it wouldn't BE-A utility function.

Inheritance means IS-A: if class A extends B, then class A IS-A B.  You must be able to use an instance of A in every context that calls for a B.

Composition means HAS-A.  Prefer composition over inheritance.

I also don't like an object-oriented design that maps objects to HTML web components.  Too coupled...

Comment: It's the recognized way of doing it, by using what WebDriver developers call "Page Objects".  That is the reason I do it that way.

Comment: Page objects are supposed to *abstract* view controls, "TablFrameOne" doesn't abstract anything - what's actually in that table?

Comment: I added a note to my original question that I hope explains it.

Comment: But if I use import static my.pkg.Util.*;  in classes that use utilities, would you consider that inheritance or composition?

Comment: Recognized by whom?  What's WebDriver?  I prefer to populate Velocity templates with dynamic data and stream the result back to the browser.  I just change the template to modify the page.  I'd ditch any library that mapped Java objects onto HTML.

Comment: Sorry, by "page objects" I am meaning JUnit tests that automate webbrowsers.  The WebDriver api uses WebKit to access page elements and manipulate the page.